# Extracting solution of SDP problem in CVX

Tags: optimization, matlab, semidefinite-programming, cvx

Assume we are given the following semidefinite program (SDP) written in MATLAB using [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/):

```
A=[1 0 1; 0 3 7; 1 7 5];
C=[1 2 3; 2 9 0; 3 0 7];
n=size(C,1);
cvx_begin
 variable X(n,n) symmetric;
 minimize trace(C*X)
 subject to
 trace(A*X) == 1;
 X == semidefinite(n);
cvx_end
```

where the optimum is found to be  `-0.385827`. How can one extract the solution for $X$, that is the values of the elements of the matrix $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CVX status is `Solved` , after CVX execution completes, the declared variables become double precision MATLAB variables, numerically populated with the optimal variable values. So `X` is a double precision variable containing the optimal value of `X`. You can display it, assign it to another variable, or anything else you can do with it in standard MATLAB.

In your problem,

```
>> disp(X)
   0.689622560343423  -0.072049779098121  -0.239704801944837
  -0.072049779098121   0.007527553887307   0.025043667211789
  -0.239704801944837   0.025043667211789   0.083318608945303
```

This is covered in the [CVX users' Guide](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not able to find it on the user guide despite being as simple.

Comment: It's a little buried. http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/solver.html#interpreting-the-results "After a complete CVX specification has been entered and the cvx_end command issued, the solver is called to generate a numerical result. It proceeds to replace the variables in your model with the computed numerical values, and creates the variable cvx_optval containing the value of the objective function."